# How to express a contour

Tags: complex-analysis

How would I express the contour which is the portion of the unit circle in the left hand plane going from i to -i.

I though the contour would be $y(t)=e^{it}$ $t {\in} [-{\pi}/2,{\pi}/2]$ but this would go through the right hand plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use $y(t)=-e^{it}$ with the same $t \in [-\pi/2,\pi/2].$ The minus sign in front makes it go in the diametrically opposite points from where your version went.

Note: at $t=-\pi/2$ this gives the right starting point $i$ as required. Then at $t=+\pi/2$ it has gotten to $-i.$ The version in the OP actually went from $-i$ to $i$ along the right half of the circle, so that by reflecting it in the origin via $z \to -z$ it ends up as required in the left half of the circle, from $i$ ending at $-i$.

Comment: should the answer be $i{\pi}$?

Comment: should the ansswer be $-i{\pi}$ since the contour starts at i, I should take that as my lower limit?

Comment: @user137090 If you keep the t range starting at $-\pi/2$ and increasing until $+\pi/2$ and you want the start to be $i$ and the end of the path to be $-i$ (and also want the path to the left of the imaginary axis), then $f(t)=-e^{it}$ works, and I don't see anything else which does, and also moves at a constant speed. BTW what do you mean in your comments by "the answer"?

Comment: sorry about that confusing post

Comment: @user137090 -- No problem. These things can be hard to get straight at first, and even after being familiar with the "tricks". Your idea of using $e^{it}$ in some range was already on the right track. If only one could express $t$ going from $+\pi/2$ and ending at $-\pi/2$ it would work, but for that one would have to be viewing the $t$ interval "mod $2\pi$" and it wouldn't be the usual way.